# How can I get page count from .ps files and record them then add them all up

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to grab page count from a directory of .ps files then record that number to a batch file. Then add the total number of pages to a variable. And also list out how many had Page Count-1 then Page Count-2 and so on up to 1,000 pages.

I have not started programming for "add the total number of pages to a variable. And also list out how many had Page Count-1 then Page Count-2 and so on up to 1,000 pages". Right now I am just trying to get the loop to work to record the page number from each postscript file in the directory to a text file.

I am having trouble setting the variables in a loop.
I think I need to use !a! instead of %a% but not sure how to format it.

The code I have was able to record the Page count to a text file just fine until I tried making it run in a loop then I broke it.
I have modified the code below with the suggestions given to me in the comments below the code.

```
@Echo On
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
REM In the next line it sets the filename to %%f and the number of lines into %%i
for %%f in (C:\qsi\mail\vlm\5\*.ps) do for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< %%f') do (
REM The next line starts at last line and backs up 4 lines to find the line with the page count in the .ps file
set startLine=%%i
set /a startLine-=4
REM The next line records the last 4 lines to a text file
more /E +!startLine! "%%f" > temp.txt
REM The next line finds the page count on the first line of the text file and sets the page count into %%a and removes the space before the number
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (C:\qsi\mail\vlm\temp.txt) do set a=%%a & SET a=!a: =!
REM The next line records the page count to a text file which will contain all page counts when loop is done.
echo !a!>>count.txt
REM Next the loop starts over if there are any .ps files left to process
)
echo END Reached & pause
```

Comment: Didn't you try `more /E +!startLine! "%%f"`?

Comment: how do I format set /a startLine=%%i - 4   it's still not working

Comment: `set startLine=%%i` then `set /a startLine-=4` then you should actually use `delayedexpansion` you enabled earlier. `more /E +!startLine! "%%f" > temp.txt`

Comment: I put delayedexpansion before the loop because I was getting an error Maximum setlocal recursion level reached since I think it was being executed every time the loop started over. There will be thousands of .ps files processed each time the batch is ran

Comment: do i need to use endlocal

Comment: I probably should mention that I have not started programming for "add the total number of pages to a variable. And also list out how many had Page Count-1 then Page Count-2 and so on up to 1,000 pages". Right now I am just trying to get the loop to work to record the page number from each postscript file in the directory.

Comment: no need to `endlocal` your script will exit `local` it once completed. The error you got was because you had it in the loop.

Comment: So have you tried to set what I mentioned?

Comment: yes and I updated the code above to reflect your suggestions but still not working.   I am getting a notice below the comments. "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"

Comment: Not working? Can you elaborate please.

Comment: I think it has something to do with my first line of code. for %%f in (C:\qsi\mail\vlm\5\*.ps) do for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< %%f') (        its causing the batch to terminate before it gets to the second line. I figured that out by adding a pause after the first line and it quits without pausing.

Comment: nevermind I fixed it. I was missing "do" at the end before the "("

Comment: Gerhard, Thank you for your help. I can't really rate you since you put everything in the comments instead of a reply. Put your comments into a reply so I can rate you a +1